# How do you pass bool and int parameters to params argument of pandas.read_sql_query

Tags: python, pandas

The type of the params argument to pandas.read_sql_query has changed in pandas 1.5.1. The API is now defined as follows:

```
def read_sql_query(sql: Any,
                   con: Any,
                   index_col: str | list[str] | None = None,
                   coerce_float: bool = True,
                   params: list[str] | dict[str, str] | None = None,
                   parse_dates: list[str] | dict[str, str] | None = None,
                   chunksize: int | None = None,
                   dtype: ExtensionDtype | str | dtype | Type[str] | Type[complex] | Type[bool] | Type[object] | dict[Hashable, ExtensionDtype | str | dtype | Type[str] | Type[complex] | Type[bool] | Type[object]] | None = None)
  -> DataFrame | Generator[DataFrame | {items}, Any, None] | {items}
```

Previously pandas 1.4.4 used the following interface:

```
def read_sql_query(
    sql,
    con,
    index_col=None,
    coerce_float: bool = True,
    params=None,
    parse_dates=None,
    chunksize: int | None = None,
    dtype: DtypeArg | None = None,
) -> DataFrame | Iterator[DataFrame]:
```

I have calls with `bool` and `int` in a `list` params that passed code inspection with pandas 1.4.4 in PyCharm. For example:

```
pandas.read_sql_query(sql=file.read(), con=connection, params=[is_simple, lookback])
```

where `is_simple` is `bool` and `lookback` is `int`.

With pandas 1.5.1 code inspection complains that the types are incorrect as it is expecting `list[str]`.  How do I pass `bool` and `int` params?  I am connecting to a SQL Server script which is expecting `INT` for `is_simple` and `lookback`.

Comment: Hi, what happens with `params=[str(int(is_simple)), str(lookback)]`?

Comment: I don't know but I am not comfortable passing int and bool as strings to SQL Server. This looks like a regression in pandas.read_sql_query. I reported the issue as a bug and someone acknowledged that the type hints need to be reset to what they were previously. See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/49716.